# istio sidecar is not restricting pod connections as desired

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar

I want to see how an istio sidecar may restrict a pod's connections (I am learning istio through its references)
so I am working with the bookinfo example, after installing the example (having a Docker Desktop) - I wrote a simple sidecar resource the restricts the connections of `ratings` to `reviews` and `details` services as following:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Sidecar
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-ratings-sidecar
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: ratings
  egress:
    - hosts:
      - "./details.default.svc.cluster.local"
      - "./reviews.default.svc.cluster.local"
```

when I run the following command `istioctl proxy-config clusters ratings-v1-5f9699cfdf-hb2gd` I really see that it includes only details.default.svc.cluster.local , reviews.default.svc.cluster.local (from the bookinfo services)
but if I run `kubectl exec ratings-v1-5f9699cfdf-hb2gd -- curl -sS productpage:9080` I get an html result i.e. it doesn't refuse the connection with productpage as if the sidecar doesn't exist
What am I missing ?
(p.s this [The result of sidecar injection was not what I expected](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/common-problems/injection/) didn't help)

Comment: Attaching similar [issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/31308), let me know if this resolves your issuse.

Comment: In sidecar yaml which is provided in the question didnt had any values w.r.t connections.  You can use istio destination rule to control connections. 
 Please refer istio documentation https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ConnectionPoolSettings  Once the DR is applied and if you take the configdump you would see those settings for that service.